# String coming through as null after apex:param

Tags: apex, visualforce, apex-param

Hi I have a lookup field which returns an opportunity if available, currently once i select an opportunity an actionsupport is triggered onchange, I then want to put that value from the lookup field into the controller using an apex:param however when i debug it in the controller its coming through as blank

Visualforce

```
<apex:inputField value="{!pb.CXT_Opportunity_Name__c}"> 
      <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!checkIfSelectedContactHasPendingOpp}"  rerender="testing">
          <apex:param name="PendingOpportunityName" assignTo="{!PendingOpportunityName}" value="{!pb.CXT_Opportunity_Name__c}"/>
      </apex:actionSupport>
</apex:inputField>
```

controller

```
public string PendingOpportunityName {get;set;}

 public pagereference checkIfSelectedContactHasPendingOpp(){
    system.debug(PendingOpportunityName);

    return null;
}
```

[image]
the debug just returns empty, any help would be awesome, Thanks

Comment: Is `CXT_Opportunity_Name__c` a Lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `CXT_Opportunity_Name__c` is a Lookup to another object, you're passing the object value to a `String` which wouldn't work.

What you'd need to do is assign the value to an instance of that object, then get the Name. For example:

**Apex Class**

```
public CXT_Pass_Registration__c PendingOpportunityName { // Change the variable to an instance of the object
    get;
    set;
}

public pagereference checkIfSelectedContactHasPendingOpp(){
    system.debug(PendingOpportunityName.Name); // Access the variable (object) and then, the Name
    return null;
}

public MyCustomController() {
    PendingOpportunityName = new CXT_Pass_Registration__c();
}
```

**Visualforce Page**

```
<apex:page controller="MyCustomController">
    <apex:inputField value="{!PendingOpportunityName.CXT_Opportunity_Name__c}" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi, its  a Lookup(Opportunity) however when i tried this i got the error : Invalid conversion from runtime type String to CXT_Pass_Registration__c

Comment: @ClevelandDan See my updates.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing rerender here. Add rerender in your `actionsupport` and also add in value in param

```
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!checkIfSelectedContactHasPendingOpp}" rerender="none"> 
       <apex:param name="PendingOpportunityName" assignTo="{!PendingOpportunityName}" value="{!pb.CXT_Opportunity_Name__c}"/>    
</apex:actionSupport>
```

Comment: I have added a rerender on the actionSupper which rerenders the outputpanel around the pageblock and added the value however its still null?

Comment: <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!checkIfSelectedContactHasPendingOpp}" rerender="testing">

Comment: <apex:param name="PendingOpportunityName" assignTo="{!PendingOpportunityName}" value="{!pb.CXT_Opportunity_Name__c}"/>

Comment: @ClevelandDan i is still not working for you?first check if there is required field and you didn't filled them then use immediate attribute.

Comment: i added the immediate="true" still nothing, I have also tried adding a actionRegion to no avail